# Test Apple Pay integration in India

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I have integrated Stripe for Payment.

The payment flow is like you book an appointment and than select Payment method.

Than when the appointment is completed Stripe will deduct the payment automatically without OTP & etc.

To accomplish the flow I had used **Stripe Setup Intent**, the payment gets deducted properly for the saved cards but doesn't work with Apple Pay. As in the Apple Pay button is visible on the *PaymentSheet* but on click of the button nothing is happening.

As I live in India I am not able to test Apple Pay Integration.
I am not able to get the logs of the errors.

I also tried using Apple Pay sandbox testing, VPN & changing the region to US.

Is there any way I can test Apple Pay integration from India?

Comment: Try with a US Apple account with a VPN.

Comment: Yeah I had created the US Apple Account, added VPN, changed the region to US. Still the button was not showing up.

Comment: Was the issue that the Apple Pay button shows but nothing happens on click, or the button doesn't show up at all? Your last reply is different from your question.

SetupIntent should work with ApplePay, maybe you are missing setting somewhere as I see inconsistent behavior(shows and unresponsive vs. doesn't show at all)

Comment: Either case, you may want to reach out to their Support

Comment: @orakaro the Apple Pay button doesn't show up at all. Users from Signapore can see the button but on click nothing happens.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale I am also getting the same issue. did you find any solution of the same

Comment: @vishnuanilkumar No I haven't found any solution to it